# Docker 0.0.0.0:55555 already in use

Tags: python, visual-studio, docker, macos-big-sur, quantconnect

I am trying to set Lean engine for python on macos using vscode as [described here](https://github.com/QuantConnect/Lean/blob/master/.vscode/readme.md#Running-Lean-in-the-Container)

When I try to run the container, I get
`docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:55555: bind: address already in use.`

This is the log output

```
A Lean container is halted and will be removed. Continue? [y/n]: y
LeanEngine
Pulling Docker image: quantconnect/lean:latest
latest: Pulling from quantconnect/lean
Digest: sha256:ff6d17d055d27da2adcde8743628768880129ea68496e8b85a94d699543664db
Status: Image is up to date for quantconnect/lean:latest
docker.io/quantconnect/lean:latest
Launching LeanEngine with command: 
docker run --rm     --mount type=bind,source=/Users/odelibalta/Documents/Code/GitHub/Lean/Launcher/config.json,target=/Lean/Launcher/config.json,readonly     -v /Users/odelibalta/Documents/Code/GitHub/Lean/Data:/Data:ro     -v /Users/odelibalta/Documents/Code/GitHub/Lean/Results:/Results     --name LeanEngine     -p 5678:5678     --expose 6000 -v /Users/odelibalta/Documents/Code/GitHub/Lean/Algorithm.Python:/Lean/Algorithm.Python -p 55555:55555     --entrypoint mono     quantconnect/lean:latest --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=0.0.0.0:55555,suspend=y     QuantConnect.Lean.Launcher.exe --data-folder /Data --results-destination-folder /Results --config /Lean/Launcher/config.json
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:55555: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

so I am very confused at the moment as I dont have anything running on 55555

```
➜  Homestead git:(release) sudo lsof -i:55555
Password:
➜  Homestead git:(release)
```

This is the same whether I am doing "Run in container" in VsCode or trying to run the container via docker desktop.

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
416ab7089c13   quantconnect/lean:latest   "mono --debug --debu…"   About a minute ago   Created             LeanEngine
```

I dont have any nginx or apache running. My hosts file is the default unaltered. The only thing I have installed is vagrant with virtual box and a Laravel homestead vm.

I'd really appreciate any input. Thank you for looking

Update

Thank's to Terry's comment, I now know that it is related to the debugging option. When I disable debugging then run the debug in container, it goes all the way. It runs the command below compared to the one above

```
docker run --rm     --mount type=bind,source=/Users/odelibalta/Documents/Code/GitHub/Lean/Launcher/config.json,target=/Lean/Launcher/config.json,readonly     -v /Users/odelibalta/Documents/Code/GitHub/Lean/Data:/Data:ro     -v /Users/odelibalta/Documents/Code/GitHub/Lean/Results:/Results     --name LeanEngine     -p 5678:5678     --expose 6000 -v /Users/odelibalta/Documents/Code/GitHub/Lean/Algorithm.Python:/Lean/Algorithm.Python quantconnect/lean:latest --data-folder /Data --results-destination-folder /Results --config /Lean/Launcher/config.json
```

Still not sure why this is happening and I would like to be able to debug. I've set the mono version to 15.8 in vscode as stated in the github instructions. I've also installed 15.8 version on my computer as well but I get the following output

```
Lean git:(master) ✗ msbuild --version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.38-preview+g300887e680 for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: --version

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

Comment: Does the debugger agent port conflict with the actual port? Can you try without the debugging config to see if it starts? If it does then I'm guessing you need to specify a different port for the debugging agent.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How can I find that information?

Comment: In your run command, get rid of the "--debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=0.0.0.0:55555,suspend=y" and see if you get the same error.

Comment: I've updated the original post. You are onto something because when I turn off debugging, the container command executes fully

Comment: That new error just means that --version isn't a valid statement. I don't use mono so not sure how helpful I can be anymore but I would guess if you wanted to use the debugger you would need to run it on a port other than 55555 as that is the port you are using to link your host/container. Does the container start successfully now without the debug statement?

Comment: No way ! It ran!!! wow thank you! I've tried changing before but I changed it only at one place and thanks to your mention I now changed it also in the vscode config for the container run task. Matched them all to a different port and it worked. Thank you so much! If you like to write your comment as a reply, I will mark it as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your run command, get rid of the "--debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=0.0.0.0:55555,suspend=y". This is trying to consume the same port which is why you are getting the address already in use error.

Running the debugger on a different port will also work as long as it isn't one of the ports you are exposing via docker.

Glad it works, thanks!